# How to switch to data transfer from charge only mode (USB) ON MY PC NOT PHONE

Tags: usb, lg-g3

I dropped my LG G3 and lost most of the responsiveness in the screen. I'm trying to access my files on my PC but I can't change my connection to being able to transfer and view the files on my phone from my PC. The setting can be changed on my phone but I can't do that anymore... Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

if you have a usb keyboard or mouse, you can use an OTG adapter and you can gain some control. From there you might be able to set a bluetooth mouse on the device, then connect the device to the PC and use the mouse to set the option.